# How to customise an image with css on a react-app application?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm currently working on a website for a client, but I'm struggling on making an image grid like this:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kut3N.jpg)

However, the hardest parts for me to achieve are: Set a grid of 4 images, responsive, where I can move the border below the image.

I've tried to set each of the images inside a div tag which I give it a border. Since I'm pretty much new into coding, I'm not sure what else should I try.

```css
div.composition {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

img.composition-photo {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div className="composition">
  <div>
    <img src={ModelOne} alt="Modelo 1" className="composition-photo img-fluid" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src={ModelTwo} alt="Modelo 2" className="composition-photo img-fluid" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src={ModelThree} alt="Modelo 3" className="composition-photo img-fluid" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src={ModelFour} alt="Modelo 4" className="composition-photo img-fluid" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your valuable help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best way, but one of the ways would be this. I hope it helps.

```css
.composition {
    position: relative;
    float: right;  
}

.composition-photo {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.composition img:nth-child(1){
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 265px;
}
.composition img:nth-child(2){
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.composition img:nth-child(3){
    position: absolute;
    top: 280px;
    right: 280px
}
.composition img:nth-child(4){
    position: absolute;
    top: 260px;
    right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="composition">
          <img src='https://guianoivaonline.com.br/wp-content/uploads/terno-para-noivo-18-700x467.jpg' alt="Modelo 1" class="composition-photo"/>
          <img src='https://guianoivaonline.com.br/wp-content/uploads/terno-para-noivo-18-700x467.jpg' alt="Modelo 2" class="composition-photo"/>
          <img src='https://guianoivaonline.com.br/wp-content/uploads/terno-para-noivo-18-700x467.jpg' alt="Modelo 3" class="composition-photo"/>
          <img src='https://guianoivaonline.com.br/wp-content/uploads/terno-para-noivo-18-700x467.jpg' alt="Modelo 4" class="composition-photo"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to set the images as in my example image, but I have one more question, if you see, all those images have a white border, how can I make that possible mate?

Comment: Good Morning, do to the same way only that using z-index, you define divs with white border and then it displaces them and uses z-index in the images to overlap the divs with white border.

Comment: I've been trying to replicate exactly the same as for the images with the only difference that I'm not using position: absolute, just setting a border, playing with the z-index and with top, bottom left, right properties as well, but whenever I do that, all images starts getting messy. Here's the code: https://codepen.io/ManudeQuevedo/pen/bOaJRp